# how to prevent a sass build of each page file when just changing a common scss file

Tags: css, sass

I have a _common.scss file which I import to various page.scss files:

page.scss:

```
@import "common";

#page {
 ...
}
```

_common.scss:

```
@import "partials/all";
@import "components/all";
...
```

But the problem is, since all my pages import _common.scss, the way I have things structured, if I make any changes inside _common.scss (or any of the files it imports), sass has to rebuild all the page css files. But if I just make _common.scss its own file and call it with a `<link>` tag (`<link href="common.css">`), then the page.scss file has errors, because it is trying to use variables and mixins defined in _common.scss and its imports.

Is it possible to structure my project so that the page.scss files can use all the mixins and variables in _common, but so that sass doesn't have to rebuild each page.css file each time I make a change to the common file? i.e. - make it so that sass only builds the common file when a change is made in common, and only builds the page file when a change is made in page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is not possible, since the aim is to have one css for each page at the end. This said it HAS to be rebuild if something is changed in common.